# How to move button to a new line with CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React and Material-UI, and creating a numpad. I have a code segment that looks like this (where `KeyPadButton` is a `RaisedButton` from Material-UI):

```
    // partially removed for brevity
    const keys = [7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0];

    return (
        <div>
            {keys.map(key => {
                return (
                    <KeyPadButton key={`button-${key}`}
                         value={key}
                         styles={[4, 1, 0].includes(key) ? styles.keypadButtonStyles : {}}

                    />
                )
            })}
        </div>
    );

const styles = {
    keypadButtonStyles: {
        clear: 'left',
        display: 'table',
    },
}
```

So, basically, I want the numbers to be displayed as:

`7, 8, 9
 4, 5, 6
 1, 2, 3
 0`

So, I want numbers `4, 1, 0` to be in the new line. I tried to apply `clear: left` and `display: table` but it moves them in a new line but they are alone in the line, whereas I want for example `5, 6` to be next to `4`, etc. I cannot use `display: block` as it breaks some default styles by Material-UI. Any ideas how to achieve what I want?

Comment: Flexbox with `flex-wrap: wrap`?

Comment: @helb Can you give a more complete example, I didn't try it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/helb/pen/mxRaYW … should work with any child elements, including `RaisedButton`

Comment: @helb Thanks, this works fine. If you can write it as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox with `flex-wrap: wrap;` should work with any child elements, including `RaisedButton`.

Working snippet (with simplified JS, the important part is CSS):

```js
const keys = [7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0];

htmlKeys = keys.map(key => `<div class=key>${key}</div>`);

document.querySelector(".keypad").innerHTML = htmlKeys.join("");
```

```css
.keypad {
  width: 12em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #333;
}

.key {
  width: 3em;
  background: #444;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class=keypad />
```

Alternative "old school" solution using `display: inline-block` (might conflict with some styling in Material UI):

```js
const keys = [7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0];

htmlKeys = keys.map(key => `<div class=key>${key}</div>`);

document.querySelector(".keypad").innerHTML = htmlKeys.join("");
```

```css
.keypad {
  width: 12em;
  background: #333;
}

.key {
  width: 3em;
  background: #444;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class=keypad />
```

Another possibility would be [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), but i think flexbox is sufficient in this case (and has a better browser support).

Comment: Btw. same thing can be achieved with just `display: inline-block` on keys (without flexbox at all), but i don't know how/if it's compatible with Material UI components…

Comment: By default the button has `display: inline-block` in Material-UI, but it doesn't seem to give the desired effect. Whereas, your solution seems to work.

Comment: @tinker i've added it to the post, it should work more or less the same if you set the width… but generally there's no reason not to use flex for it :)